# PDF con ReportLab Como hacer que el texto dentro de una tabla no se salga

Tags: django, reportlab

Hola necesito saber como hacer que en el documento PDF que genero en mi sitio, el texto que va dentro de una columna no se salga y si la columna no es lo suficientemente ancha que continue debajo. Observen la tabla ACUERDOS DE NIVEL DE SERVICIOS esta foto es del PDF y veran cual es el problema.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo en la view.py es el siguiente:

```
def pdf_export(request):
id_cont=request.GET['id']
filename="Contrato de CubanCloud_"+request.user.first_name+"_"+request.user.last_name+".pdf"
# Creamos el response
response=HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition']='attachment; filename="%s"' % filename
# Observa que ahora en vez de usar el nombre del archivo usamos el response
doc=SimpleDocTemplate(
    response,
    pagesize=letter,
    rightMargin=72,
    leftMargin=72,
    topMargin=2,
    bottomMargin=18,
)
Story=[]
im=Image(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/LogoCubanCloudPDF1.png', width=550, height=70)
Story.append(im)
styles=getSampleStyleSheet()
datos1=Paragraph('NOMBRE Y APELLIDO(S) DEL CLIENTE: '+request.user.first_name+' '+request.user.last_name,styles['Normal'])
datos2=Paragraph('NOMBRE DE USUARIO: '+request.user.username,styles['Normal'])
Story.append(datos1)
Story.append(datos2)
datos3=Paragraph('E-MAIL: '+request.user.email,styles['Normal'])
Story.append(datos3)
noContrato=Paragraph('NO. CONTRATO: '+str(id_cont),styles['Normal'])
Story.append(noContrato)
p=Image(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'/espacioPDF.png',width=550, height=30)
Story.append(p)
encabezados=('Servicios Contratados', 'ID.Servicio', 'Plan', 'Precio')
lista_nombres=[]
for var in Servicio_Contratado.objects.filter(contrato_id=id_cont):
    lista_nombres.append((var.nombre, var.pk, str(var.plazo) + " días", var.precio))
lista_nombres.reverse()
detalle_orden=Table([encabezados] + lista_nombres,colWidths=[170,100,100,100])
# Aplicamos estilos a las celdas de la tabla
detalle_orden.setStyle(TableStyle(
    [
        ('GRID', (0, 0), (3, -1), 1, colors.dodgerblue),
        ('LINEBELOW', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 2, colors.darkblue),
        ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.dodgerblue)
        # # La primera fila(encabezados) va a estar centrada
        # ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (0, 0), 'CENTER'),
        # # Los bordes de todas las celdas serán de color negro y con un grosor de 1
        # ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0, colors.transparent),
        # # El tamaño de las letras de cada una de las celdas será de 10
        # ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (0, 0), 10),

    ]
))
Story.append(detalle_orden)
p=Image(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/espacioPDF.png', width=550, height=30)
Story.append(p)
p=Paragraph('ACUERDOS DE NIVEL DE SERVICIOS',styles['Normal'])
Story.append(p)
encabezados=['No.', 'AsL']
lista_acl=[]
for var in Asl.objects.filter(generales=True):
    lista_acl.append((var.pk, var.descripcion))
lista_acl.reverse()
detalle_orden=Table([encabezados] + lista_acl,colWidths=[70,400,0])
# Aplicamos estilos a las celdas de la tabla
detalle_orden.setStyle(TableStyle(
    [
        ('GRID', (0, 0), (3, -1), 1, colors.dodgerblue),
        ('LINEBELOW', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 2, colors.darkblue),
        ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.dodgerblue)
        # # La primera fila(encabezados) va a estar centrada
        # ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (0, 0), 'CENTER'),
        # # Los bordes de todas las celdas serán de color negro y con un grosor de 1
        # ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0, colors.transparent),
        # # El tamaño de las letras de cada una de las celdas será de 10
        # ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (0, 0), 10),

    ]
))
Story.append(detalle_orden)
doc.build(Story)
return response
```

Answer (score 1):

En la tabla de los ACUERDOS DE NIVEL DE SERVICIO hay que añadir una linea de codigo, queda así:

```
    for var in Asl.objects.filter(generales=True):
    # creo variable p para guardar la descripcion
    p=Paragraph(var.descripcion, styles['Normal'])
    # añado a la lista la llave primaria de acl y ademas la descripcion contenida en p
    lista_acl.append((var.pk, p))
detalle_orden=Table([encabezados] + lista_acl,colWidths=[70,400])
```

El detalle está en el ciclo for, dentro de el hay que pasar a una variable de tipo Paragraph el contenido del atributo descripción. Y luego pasarle a la lista_acl la variable de tipo Paragraph. 
El resultado es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
 Espero que les sirva. Bendiciones